# Processing forms

Tags: php, post

I am trying to find a cleaner way to process POST data.  Here is my form:

```
Email <input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
Subject <input type="text" name="subject" /><br/>
Message <input type="text" name="body" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I created a PHP page to process the form and called a class like this:

```
$mail = new Email();
$mail->processPost($_POST);
```

In my class, I have:

```
function processPost($post) {
 foreach($post as $key => $value) {
 $_POST[$key] = $$value;
 }
}

function Email($to, $subject, $body) {
 $this->processPost->email;
 $this->processPost->subject;
 $this->processPost->body;  
}
```

But I am not sure how to set the variables as public in the processPost function so they are available to the Email function.  I'd appreciate some help with this.  I'm not getting any output from the processPost function when I call it as above and then try to echo the variables below it.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed coding some of the code as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe something like this ?

```
<?php
class Email
{
  protected $to = '';
  protected $subject = '';
  protected $body = '';

  public function __construct( $to, $subject, $body )
  {
     // TODO: Validate input with `filter_var`

     $this->to = $to;
     $this->subject = $subject;
     $this->body = $body;
  }

  public static function fromArray( array $array )
  {
    // TODO: Validate $array with `filter_var_array`

    return new self($array['to'], $array['subject'], $array['body']);
  }

  public function send()
  {
    // TODO: Implement send() function
  }
}

$mail = Email::fromArray($_POST);
$mail->send();
```

PS: This example is in PHP5, it doesn't work in PHP4.

Comment: Thanks, Joksnet.  I was hoping that I could write a class that would be flexible enough that I could in a very abstract way process all of the variables in the post, assigning the variables on the fly.  Part of the results I want are to dyanmically generate $email = $_POST['email'], $subject = $_POST['subject'], etc, where the key is assigned to the variable name, so I can then work with those variables in other parts of the script.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure what you're trying to do in your postProcess function here:

> foreach($post as $key => $value) {
>    $_POST[$key] = $$value;
>    }

the double dollar is assigning $_POST[$key] to the value of the variable $$value (ex $email) but $email variable has no value from what I can tell.

now, why are you assigning it to $_POST[$key] instead of $this->processPost[$key] ? If you did it that way, you should be able to access the value in the Email function: $this->processPost['email']

Apologies if I misread the question

Comment: No, you got it right.  I rewrote it as this: public function processPost($post) {
   foreach($post as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $_POST[$key];  How do I then get the variables from this function and use them in other functions.  Do I need to make them public, or do I access them with $this->processPost->email (where that is referencing $email from the processPost function?
   }
  }

Comment: i would do something like :
foreach ($post as $key=>$value){$this->postProcess[$key] = someSecurityEscapeCheck($value);}

I believe in php 4 or 5, if you assign to a member variable that you haven't declared in the class, it's automatically public. Then in the Email Function, you access it with:

$this->postProcess['email'] 

(and you don't need to pass it into the function)
I added a fake function to escape the post parameters because you're going to want to protect against malicious inputs. But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Email {

    public $data=array();

    function __construct($array=array())
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            $this->data[$key] = $value; 

        }
        return (object) $this->data; /* :D */
    }

    function get($key='')
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}

$foo = new Email($_POST);

echo $foo->get('email');
echo $foo->get('subject');
?>
```

Comment: im not entirely sure what this does but it echoed out the $_POST values so i was happy. i wouldn't recommend using it

Comment: Thanks, Ross.  I think I'm going about this wrong.  I'm new to doing it this way (writing functions).

Comment: Ross, I want to grab all of the variables from the post and as assign them to variables I can use elsewhere in the class, so I can then create a send function with all of those variables.

Comment: well, the way i (poorly) demonstrated above, sort of does that. you can access the variables just by doing `$this->data['some_field']` any where within your class, as it is publicly accessible. I'm not aware of any way to *dynamically* assign variables other than setting and getting them with `$this->`. but i'm a total oop failure. If you were to use my poor example, you can just use `$email = $this->get('email');` within your functions after the form has been submit.